# How to stop content script from starting itself

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My manifest.json matches every URL. So, whenever, a URL is opened in Chrome, the content script is activated.

**Current procedure:**

(1) My background script updates the current empty URL to something.

(2) My content script is activated, because it's a match in the manifest.json. My content script needs to visit multiple URLs on the same website. It clicks on a link and navigates back (= everything in one tab) -> The content script calls itself again, because another URL is opened.

**Problem:**

I don't want content script to call itself multiple times. It should for example only activate, when it gets a message from the background script that a new URL was opened.

**Thoughts:**

chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function()) is around all my code in the background script. Is there something similar for the content script that i'm looking for?

**Maybe something like:**

- window.addEventListener
- browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener
- browser.runtime.sendMessage
- browser.runtime.onMessage
- browser.tabs.sendMessage()

But i don't understand how to use them properly.

Comment: Remove "content_scripts" section from manifest.json completely and use [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#functionality) instead.

Comment: So i will not have a .js for the content script and put everything in the background.js?

Comment: No, you'll have two scripts, see the documentation I've linked.

Answer (score 1):

In your background script, do this:

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
    let msg = {txt: "execute"};
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
};
```

And then in your content script, you can intercept this message via:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
    if(msg.txt == "execute") {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Docs here.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage

Comment: Thank you! The content script won't activate now, though.

Comment: @aj93 Can you post your full scripts somewhere? See if the console logs are throwing anything, and make sure the package is updated and not cached